# Deserializing objects from a file using Gson, JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gson

Deserializing objects from a file using Gson, JavaFX.

I want to learn how to parse through the library and transfer the received data to JavaFX.
stack: JavaFX21 and Gson.

**FXController**

```
public class FxController {

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    public void initialize() {
        getParserFile();
    }

    public void getParserFile() {
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("library.json");
            Book root = gson.fromJson(reader, Book.class);
           // System.out.println(root);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Parser error " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception in Application start method**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)    
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)   
at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)  
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)    
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)   
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method   
at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)     
at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)     
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
```

yes, but it didn't help

Comment: That's not the full stack trace. It's missing the most important information: The [cause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause()) (and message, if there is one) of the `LoadException`. See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627) for more information about reading stack traces. For more specific help, please [edit] your question to add the full stack trace, as well as a [mre] demonstrating the error.

Comment: Related: [Cannot import Gson into my JavaFX Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77581756/cannot-import-gson-into-my-javafx-maven-project).